# Do Request/Reply with camel-sjms without using temporary queues

Tags: jms, apache-camel

Currently, for doing request/reply with camel-sjms, I'm using the exchangePattern=InOut URI parameter like this:

```
from("sjms:queue:my.queue?exchangePattern=InOut")
 .setBody(constant("This is an example message"));
```

And when looking at the message headers, I see it creates a temporary queue through the JMSDestination header to do the exchange.

The problem with temporary queues is that, when doing a lot of request/reply, it can be a big performance hit, so instead, based on previous experience, on plain JMS, I've used instead a message to a normal queue, but I can achieve request/reply through JMSCorrelationID message filtering.

So, how can do a request/reply in camel-sjms but with normal queues instead of temporary queue creation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation of camel-sjms and you can find the option `namedReplyTo` where you can specify the reply-to queue name to use.

- http://camel.apache.org/sjms